# Remove selection image from tabbar item on modal view dismiss

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a tab bar based app.

I have selected/de-selected image set for every tab bar item.

On first tab I have a button that opens up modalviewcontroller.

At the time when modal view is activated, my tab bar item state is selected and has selection image.

when modal view pops up , selection image is still there. But when I dismiss modal view, I want selction image of tab bar item changed to some other image.

How do I change this image on modal view dismiss?

I'm trying to so following, but it doesn't work:

```
[[[self.tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0 ] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"abc.png"] ];
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The titles and images of the tab bar items are supposed to be set by the controller in that tab, not the tab bar controller. So, you should try changing that tab in the controller in the first tab. The method you're using is for a stand-alone tab bar, not one that's controlled by a tab bar controller. You can do that like this:

```
-(void)changeTitle{
    [self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.jpg"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"two.jpg"]];
}
```

Comment: i tried  self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]; but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use this may it help you:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[self.tabBar.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0];
[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ab.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]];
```

Comment: But in my case, tab is not changed, only modal view appears and is dismissed. This doesn't work on modal view dismiss.